# Algorithm for placing nodes in a graph

Tags: graph

I have been trying to create an algorithm that can create a graph. It is not a tree graph as nodes can have multiple parents, more like an activity diagram. My problem is with placing nodes on the x axis, making sure that they do not overlap each other. I have been looking around for months now, but I have been unable to find any information relevant to this kind of graph. So I where wondering if some of you people might know of an algorithm that can solve this problem, or an idea on what approach I should take.

[image]

Here you see my problem: The red nodes are overlapping other nodes

[image]

My best approach right now is where i add it all to row:
[image]

With this approach will the tree above look like this.
[image]

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: The idea about, where i place the objects in rows is what i am currently implementing